# java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<400>

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

it's my controller...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public @ResponseBody ResponseMessage getUser(@RequestBody AvailableUser uuid) {
    logger.info("enter into getuser method's body");
    return Manager.availableUser(uuid);
}
```

it's my testcontroller...

```
@Test 
public void testgetUser() throws Exception 
{
    AvailableUser availableUser=new AvailableUser();
    List<String> lst =new ArrayList<String>();
    lst.add("test1");
    lst.add("test2");
    availableUser.setUuId(lst);
    this.mockMvc.perform(post("/user").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isCreated())
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
         when(Manager.availableUser(availableUser)).thenReturn(message);
}
```

I don't know how to pass the object when controller method call `("/user")` form `testcontroller`.

and I got error message `java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<400>`

Comment: Maybe because you did not provide any body to your request. Try to add .content(availableUser) to your post

Comment: when i add {.content(availableUser)} i got error msg."The method content(byte[]) in the type MockHttpServletRequestBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (AvailableUser)"

Comment: I didnt get why the "Accept" is added to headers in controller ? Is that required when we have consumes/produces ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Jackson, the simplest approach is to serialize the `AvailableUser` to JSON String using an instance of `ObjectMapper`:

```
@Test 
public void testgetUser() throws Exception 
{
    // Same stuff
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    this.mockMvc
        .perform(
                  post("/user")
                 .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                 .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                 .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(availableUser))
        )
        .andExpect(status().isCreated())
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
    // Same as before
}
```